# How do I add the days to a date?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know about the `DateTime` and the `AddDays()` commands. But I need to take the date in my txtDateTime.Text textbox and have the nights spent in my txtNights.Text. Just because I have no idea how to add the two together and display them in a third texbox, here is all my code...

```
public partial class Request : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDateTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("d");

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Calendar1.Visible = false;
        }

        txtDateTime.Focus();

    }
    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void imgCalendar_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Calendar1.Visible)
        {
            Calendar1.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Calendar1.Visible = true;
        }    
    }
    protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDateTime.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
    }
    protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblThank.Text = "Thank you for your request";

        double dblNights = 0;

//Validation
        //Validation of Nights
        try
        {
            dblNights = Convert.ToDouble(txtNights.Text);

            if (double.TryParse(txtNights.Text, out dblNights))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                string script = "alert(\"Number of Nights Must be between 1 and 14!\");";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                                  "ServerControlScript", script, true);
                txtNights.Focus();
            }
        }//End Try

        catch
        {
            string script = "alert(\"Number of Nights Must be an Integer!\");";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                                  "ServerControlScript", script, true);


            txtNights.Focus();
        }//End Catch



        //End Nights Validation
   //validation of Email/Name Fields
        Boolean blnErrors = false;

        if (txtName.Text == "")
        {
            string script = "alert(\"Name Field Is Required!\");";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                                  "ServerControlScript", script, true);

            txtName.Focus();
        }

        if (txtEmail.Text == "")
        {
            string script = "alert(\"Email Field Is Required!\");";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                                  "ServerControlScript", script, true);

            txtEmail.Focus();
        }

    //End Validation of Email/Name Fields
//End ALL Validation


  //Depparture Date

        DateTime arrivalDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;

        DateTime departureDate = arrivalDate.AddDays(1);

        string formattedDate = departureDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy");

        formattedDate = txtDeparture.Text;





    }//End Submit
    protected void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDateTime.Text = "";
        txtEmail.Text = "";
        txtName.Text = "";
        txtNights.Text = "";
        txtSpecial.Text = "";

        radKing.Checked = false;
        radStandard.Checked = false;
        radSuite.Checked = false;
        radBusiness.Checked = false;
        radDouble.Checked = false;
    }
    protected void txtDeparture_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DateTime arrivalDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;

        DateTime departureDate = arrivalDate.AddDays(1);

        string formattedDate = departureDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy");

        formattedDate = txtDeparture.Text;


    }
}
```

I need to take the date selected in my `txtDateTime.Text` have the number of nights staying that was entered into my `txtNights.Text` and have those two added up and displayed in a third box called `txtDeparture.Text`

How do I go about doing this with the `DateTime` and `AddDays()`?

Comment: It's very hard to tell what *exactly* the problem is - you've posted a  large amount of code, with all kinds of somewhat irrelevant bits - but your `txtDeparture_TextChanged` appears to be adding a single day... why aren't you just parsing `txtNights.Text` as an integer and using that instead?

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi 1 night is just 1 day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a little confused, but I think this is what you're looking for?

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(txtDateTime.Text);
int daysToSpend = int.Parse(txtNights.Text);
DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(daysToSpend);
```

Comment: Since he's using a calendar control, i'd assume these string representations of a datetime.  He's probably looking to find the difference in days between two datetimes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify `\\Departure Date` section in `btnSubmit_Click(` method

Currrently you have coded to add 1 day. You need to change the following lines.

```
DateTime arrivalDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;  
DateTime departureDate = arrivalDate.AddDays(1);    
string formattedDate = departureDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy");  
formattedDate = txtDeparture.Text;
```

to the following

```
DateTime arrivalDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDateTime.Text);
DateTime departureDate = arrivalDate.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(txtNights.Text));   
string formattedDate = departureDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy");  
txtDeparture.Text = formattedDate;
```

or to do it in less code.

```
DateTime arrivalDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDateTime.Text);
txtDeparture.Text = arrivalDate.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(txtNights.Text)).ToString("dd/MM/yy");
```

Comment: The OP already knows about `AddDays` - the code already includes it. It *looks* like they just didn't know what to do about the number of days to add...